# pandas to find match in column1 and update corresponding row on a column2

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("df.csv")
```

**df**

```
_id,column1,column2
1,FullName,
2,xyz,
3,custname,
4,FullNm,
5,FirstName,
6,abc
```

*If any value in column1 is made up of only given set of keywords in this case(full, name, nm, txt, dsc) and here keyword "full" is mandatory exists then update "column2" as "Full Name" other wise leave it empty. how can we use the regex to achieve or if any other easy method*

*I was trying to do this with*

```
df.column2 = df.column1.str.replace('full|name|nm|txt|dsc',"Full Name")
```

*I'm getting a wrong output:*

```
_id,column1,column2
1,FullName,FullName
2,xyz,xyz
3,custname,custname
4,FullNm,FullNm
5,FirstName,FirstName
6,abc,abc
```

Where desired output:

```
_id,column1,column2
1,FullName,Full Name
2,xyz,
3,custname,
4,FullNm,Full Name
5,FirstName,
6,abc
```

I could easily achieve this using awk:

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, 'gensub(/full|name|nm|txt|dsc[0-9]*/,"","g",tolower($2))=="" {$3="Full Name"; print $0}' df.csv| awk -F , -v OFS=, '(tolower($2) ~ /full/) {print $0}'
```

**Condition**

Given set of keywords - full|name|nm|txt|dsc[0-9] mandatory keyword
- full

***following are the cases where it is failing to match the conditions.***

**Case1**

`custfullname` - here cust is not in given set of words so don't update column2

**Case2**

`txtnmdsc` - here value is made of given set of keywords but doesn't contain mandatory keyword.

following are the condition it matches :

```
fulltxt1
fulldsc
fullname
full
full123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), to check for the condition. if column1 [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) `full`, then column2 stays the same, if not, replace with empty string :

Keeping it simple, and using the exact matches you provided:

```
words = ["fulltxt1", "fulldsc", "fullname", "full", "full123"]
check = f"{'|'.join(words)}"
print(check)
'fulltxt1|fulldsc|fullname|full|full123'

 df.column2 = np.where(df.column1.str.contains(check, case=False), "Full Name", "")

       _id  column1     column2
   0    1   FullName    Full Name
   1    2   xyz 
   2    3   custname    
   3    4   FullNm      Full Name
   4    5   FirstName   
   5    6   abc
```

Comment: thanks - but my match condition - If any value in column1 is made up of only given set of keywords in this case(full, name, nm, txt, dsc) and here keyword "full" is mandatory exists then update "column2" as "Full Name" other wise leave it empty. It shouldn't be based on only one keyword it should have to include other keywords as well in condition.

Comment: I updated the code, let me know if it fits with what you are after

Comment: thanks I've updated the conditions with explanation where conditions matches and where it doesn't matches.

Comment: can we include a patter to include any number like - [0-9]

Comment: I updated the code to match the exact conditions you supplied.

Comment: Can I add a regex pattern as keyword like [0-9]

Comment: yes, you can add a regex pattern. by default, ``str contains`` works with regex

Comment: @@sammywemmy  I've got one problem with this code. I will open another question for that.